# How to write the syntax grammar of this diagram

Tags: graph, syntax, bnf, ebnf

I am trying to write the syntax grammar of the below diagram but I didn't succeed. 
I tried

```
Choice   ::= letter ( ( 'digit' | '_' ) letter )
```

but it is totally wrong.
How can I write the Syntax of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax in EBNF like notation would be:

```
<name> = <letter> (<letter> | <digit> | <underscore>)*
```